# Chrome 24 UI is unchanged eventhough selenium executes the actions

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My test cases were working fine with selenium+chrome 23. I upgraded to chrome browser 24 and tried running the cases. although selenium executes the cases, the changes are not reflected in UI sometimes. I am using chrome driver 26 and selenium webdriver 2.29.

Comment: Sample test case where this happens?

Comment: I have a login page. Although webdriver says it types them,and clicks on login. The webdriver proceeds with clicks, and other operations on the next page. But I actually don't see the next page. saving the screenshot from selenium works though

Comment: Can you make this into a small sample case? Otherwise, no one can verify if this is an issue with your code/HTML or the ChromeDriver itself. I'd also be interested to see if the test passes with the FirefoxDriver?

Comment: You're not alone - seems like new Chrome has some issues. I've got the same problem, and here's issue for Selenium I've found: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5029

Comment: The test cases pass with Firefox. Seems the issue is present only in chrome